# Click Button Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<div class="follow_form">        <a class="button follow_button follow_button_3713620 grey" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/unfollow/3713620">Following</a>
</div>
```

Trying to click all buttons where rel="nofollow"

```
javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('rel'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }
```

^not working, because class name is different for each button, but "rel" stays the same for all buttons.

Comment: $('a[rel=nofollow]').trigger('click'); if you're using jQuery...

Comment: Code:

    <a class="button follow_button follow_button_3854378 green" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/follow/3854378">Follow</a>

I want to click all the follow buttons, but the number in the class changes. Is there any arguments I can put in after follow_button such as * to ignore the number after? Maybe click everything with the label "Follow" like in the end of the code?

javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('class here'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }

Comment: It shouldn't matter if the number changes, as there seems to be a follow_button class and a follow_button_1234567 class (where the number changes as you say), so if they all have the follow_button class without a number after, can't you just select using that ($('.follow_button').trigger('click'))? If you want to select by the Follow text (strange, but ok) you can do $('a:contains("Follow")').trigger('click'); BTW, if you have different requirements, you should post those in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a javascript only solution. It is supported in modern browsers only. However, appx [95% of browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector) fully support it.

Added in the ability to check if the string `"follow_button"` exists in the class before clicking.

```
javascript:var inputs = document.querySelectorAll("[rel='nofollow']");
for (var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { 
    if (inputs[i].className.indexOf("follow_button") > -1) {
        inputs[i].click();
    }
}
```

Comment: Second question.

Code:

<div class="user_action">
   <div class="follow_form">
            <a class="button follow_button follow_button_3854378 green" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/follow/3854378">Follow</a>

   </div>

   
    <div class="friend_form friend_form_3854378">
     <a class="button friend_button add_friend_button green" id="friend_button_3854378" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="/friendships/create/3854378">Add Friend</a>
</div>
  </div>


I want to only click the follow buttons, but # changes in class.

Comment: The class for the follow button is "button follow_button follow_button_3854378 green"

Comment: The issue is, the number in that class changes, Is there a way to click all buttons in that class with an argument: "button follow_button *"??

Comment: <a class="button follow_button follow_button_3854378 green" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/follow/3854378">Follow</a>

Or click everything with the label "Follow".

Comment: @ArturasRosenbacher updated to include a class selector. I only had it select on `"follow_button"` since the order of `"button follow_button"` may be out of order. `"follow_button"` should be unique enough from what I'm seeing to select what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Using JQuery you can do it by this way (I added an id, so when you click over some link, the current id is logged in the console, add you custom code here, call a function, etc):

Supose more than one link:

```
<div class="follow_form">        
    <a id="follow_button_371hjh" class="button follow_button follow_button_371hjh grey" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/unfollow/3713620">Following</a>

    <a id="follow_button_12312ss" class="button follow_button follow_button_371hjh grey" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/unfollow/3713620">Following</a>
</div>
```

The with Jquery, you can obtain the current clicked link with this:

```
$(".follow_form").on("click", "[id^=follow_button_]", function() {
    console.log("Link pressed: " + $(this).attr("id"));
});
```

Look in this: http://jsfiddle.net/c2j9toLy/

Comment: Code:

    <a class="button follow_button follow_button_3854378 green" data-remote="true" rel="nofollow" data-method="patch" href="http://www.tsu.co/follow/3854378">Follow</a>

I want to click all the follow buttons, but the number in the class changes. Is there any arguments I can put in after follow_button such as * to ignore the number after? Maybe click everything with the label "Follow" like in the end of the code?

javascript:var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('class here'); for(var i=0; i<inputs.length;i++) { inputs[i].click(); }

Comment: We this approach you can't, but try to add the follow_button_"the number" like an id. Then you can follow this apporach. I update the code in the answer

Comment: For comment, think that an id have to be an unique identifier, and a class is supposed to be reused in a lot of tags.